# Regex Double Quotes and html tags

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I read data from csv file. And wrote it to string and now need to classify those data.

```
  if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['app_bundle_upload_type']['tmp_name']['file'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           $num = count($data);
           $row++;
           for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
               $result.= $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
           }
      }
 }
```

How Can I correctly use Regex to group this sort od data. I do care about everything inside " ". I tried regex = '/"(.*?)"/s'; But can't escape double quotes inside other quotes. What shall I do ? And ofc there's this whole html data which I do not have right now what to do.

That is my string

> 1;"admin_loginIncorrect";"Podane hasło jest nieprawidłowe";"1";"0"
>   2;"admin_logOut";"Wyloguj";"1";"0" 
>   3786;"tutorial_text_3";"Wenn Sie
>   ein Produkt kaufen möchten dessen Preis Sie soeben aufgedeckt haben
>   tun Sie es schnell und klicken Sie auf **""kaufen""** - Sie haben dafür
>   20 Sekunden. Sie können aber eine Stunde oder einen Tag warten um zu
>   sehen ob der Preis noch weiter fällt. Das Aufdecken des Preises von
>   anderen Benutzern reduziert den Preis kontinuierlich weiter. Denken
>   Sie jedoch daran dass wenn Sie zu lange warten jemand wird schneller
>   sein als Sie!. ;5";"0" 3914;"auction_desc_22297";"MacBook 12" 256GB - Space Gray
> 256 GB pamięci masowej flash z magistralą PCIe
>   na płycie głównejDwurdzeniowy procesorIntel Core
>   m3 1,1 GHzTurbo Boost do 2,2 GHz8 GB pamięci
>   RAMIntel HD Graphics 515
> Zawartość
>   opakowaniaMacBookZasilacz USB-C o mocy 29 WPrzewód zasilający USB-C (2 m)
> Cena zawiera koszt przesyłki."'"5";"0"

@EDIT
I started in wrong way. Using regex was to complex task. Thanks to `fgetcsv` i could do it a lot easier

```
 if (($handle = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) { .... }}
```

It reads row by row and give it back in array

$data[$i]

Comment: You could try doing something like, split on ; (since that really seems to be the delimiter) and then strip the leading and trailing ".  That should get you the data you want including the quotes in the middle.  If that works I can write up a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $string = '1;"admin_loginIncorrect";"Podane hasło jest nieprawidłowe";"1";"0" 2;"admin_logOut";"Wyloguj";"1";"0" 3786;"tutorial_text_3";"Wenn Sie ein Produkt kaufen möchten dessen Preis Sie soeben aufgedeckt haben tun Sie es schnell und klicken Sie auf ""kaufen"" - Sie haben dafür 20 Sekunden. Sie können aber eine Stunde oder einen Tag warten um zu sehen ob der Preis noch weiter fällt. Das Aufdecken des Preises von anderen Benutzern reduziert den Preis kontinuierlich weiter. Denken Sie jedoch daran dass wenn Sie zu lange warten jemand wird schneller sein als Sie!. ;5";"0" 3914;"auction_desc_22297";"MacBook 12" 256GB - Space Gray
    256 GB pamięci masowej flash z magistralą PCIe na płycie głównejDwurdzeniowy procesorIntel Core m3 1,1 GHzTurbo Boost do 2,2 GHz8 GB pamięci RAMIntel HD Graphics 515
    Zawartość opakowaniaMacBookZasilacz USB-C o mocy 29 WPrzewód zasilający USB-C (2 m)
    Cena zawiera koszt przesyłki."\'"5";"0"';

    $regex = '#"(?<quotes>[^"]*)"#';

    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

    var_dump($matches['quotes']);
```

See it here : https://3v4l.org/8Z8J5

Comment: It skips second value "Podane hasło jest nieprawidłowe"

In fact it skips much more values

Comment: Ah yes, weird non standard characters, regex just needs tweaking a bit

Comment: Still same. It skip a lot

Comment: we need something smarter than `\w+`

Comment: A litte better but there's still problem with "   " "   " double quotes

 [12194]=> string(6) "kaufen"